# Ajax: send Array to php correctly?

Tags: ajax

i have filled an array like this:

***JS***

```
 playersDone["gk"] = "test";
 playersDone["df1"] = "test2";
```

and my **ajax** part looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'writeDraftedTeamToDraftsDatabase.php',
    type:'post',
    data:{players: JSON.stringify(playersDone)},

    success: function (res) {                        
        alert(res);                    
    }
});
```

and my **php** looks like this:

```
echo $_POST['players']['gk'];
```

but with this way I cant get the value of my Array Element correctly!

Like you see I'Ve already tried to pass the array with JSON.stringify() but without success!

Could you maybe give me a hint where my mistake is?

Thanks you very much!

Comment: Why are you calling JSON.stringify when the AJAX method will already serialize the data for PHP?

Comment: because I get this out of another stackoverflow question....

Answer (score 0):

ok here is my solution:

**JS / AJAX**

```
var playersDone = {};  // THIS IS IMPORTANT, not var playersDone = [] becasue js works with objects not with assoc. arrays !!!

$.ajax({
            url:'writeDraftedTeamToDraftsDatabase.php',
            type:'post',
            data:{'players':playersDone},
            success: function (res) {                        
                alert(res);                        
            }
        });
```

**PHP**

```
$data = $_POST['players'];    
echo json_encode($data);
```

Edit: an also a really good way was to use the webDevelopsers Tool of Firefox to check the Ajax Request header, becauser after that i recognized that my request content was empty... ;) and i knew "ok empty string was sent" something is wrong on js / client side!